# Operation $\circ$ on $\mathbb{R}: x\circ y=x\sqrt{1+y^2}+y\sqrt{1+x^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, binary-operations

I have the following operation $\circ$ on $\mathbb{R}: x\circ y=x\sqrt{1+y^2}+y\sqrt{1+x^2}, \forall x, y\in \mathbb{R}$.
My question: are the groups $(\mathbb{R},\circ)$ and $(\mathbb{R},+)$ isomorphic? $"+"$ is the standard addition operation. Thank you!

EDIT: As I said in the comments section below, $(\mathbb{R},\circ)$ is a group.

Comment: How do you know that $(\mathbb{R},\circ)$ is a group ?

Comment: Already checked it.

Comment: Which map? We need to define a bijection which satisfies $f(x\circ y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Comment: Yes, I checked everything. $(\mathbb{R},\circ)$ is a group otherwise I wouldn't ask such a question........

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well if you find a bijection $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x + y) = f(x) \circ f(y)$ (or the reverse), then $(\mathbb{R}, \circ)$ will automatically be a group...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, but this was not the point. The OP wrote "My question: are the groups isomorphic?" without telling us that both are indeed groups. Hence my comment  Then the OP clarified it.I tried for a moment to give a counterexample to associativity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they are:

$$ (\sinh u)\circ (\sinh v) = \sinh(u)\cosh(v)+\sinh(v)\cosh(u) = \sinh(u+v) $$
and $\sinh$ is a bijective function on $\mathbb{R}$. That also gives:

$$\underbrace{x\circ x\circ\ldots\circ x}_\text{n times}=\sinh\left(n\cdot\text{arcsinh}(x)\right)=\frac{\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^n-\left(-x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^{n}}{2},$$
so:
$$ \underbrace{x\circ x\circ\ldots\circ x}_\text{(2n+1) times}=i^{2n-1}\, T_{2n+1}(ix),\qquad \underbrace{x\circ x\circ\ldots\circ x}_\text{2n times}=i^{2n-1}\sqrt{1+x^2}\,U_{2n-1}(ix)$$
where $T_n,U_n$ are [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Comment: @user95553: appended to my answer.